# SQL: multiple counts from same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am having a real problem trying to get a query with the data I need. I have tried a few methods without success. I can get the data with 4 separate queries, just can't get hem into 1 query. All data comes from 1 table. I will list as much info as I can.

My data looks like this. I have a `customerID` and 3 columns that record who has worked on the record for that customer as well as the assigned acct manager

```
 RecID_Customer___CreatedBy____LastUser____AcctMan

 1-------1374----------Bob Jones--------Mary Willis------Bob Jones

 2-------1375----------Mary Willis------Bob Jones--------Bob Jones

 3-------1376----------Jay Scott--------Mary Willis-------Mary Willis

 4-------1377----------Jay Scott--------Mary Willis------Jay Scott

 5-------1378----------Bob Jones--------Jay Scott--------Jay Scott
```

I want the query to return the following data. See below for a description of how each is obtained.

```
Employee___Created__Modified__Mod Own__Created Own 

 Bob Jones--------2-----------1---------------1----------------1

 Mary Willis------1-----------2---------------1----------------0

 Jay Scott--------2-----------1---------------1----------------1
```

> Created = Counts the number of records created by each Employee
>
> Modified = Number of records where the Employee is listed as Last User
>   (except where they created the record)
>
> Mod Own = Number of records for each where the LastUser = Acctman
>   (account manager)
>
> Created Own = Number of Records created by the employee where they are
>   the account manager for that customer

I can get each of these from a query, just need to somehow combine them:

```
Select CreatedBy, COUNT(CreatedBy) as Created
FROM [dbo].[Cust_REc] GROUP By CreatedBy

Select LastUser, COUNT(LastUser) as Modified
FROM [dbo].[Cust_REc] Where LastUser != CreatedBy GROUP By LastUser

Select AcctMan, COUNT(AcctMan) as CreatePort
FROM [dbo].[Cust_REc] Where AcctMan = CreatedBy GROUP By AcctMan

Select AcctMan, COUNT(AcctMan) as ModPort
FROM [dbo].[Cust_REc] Where AcctMan = LastUser AND NOT AcctMan = CreatedBy GROUP By AcctMan
```

Can someone see a way to do this? I may have to join the table to itself, but my attempts have not given me the correct data.

Comment: Are you trying to avoid sub queries?

Comment: Sub queries are fine.

Comment: The first answer by SlimsGhost works awesome. I didn't think of using an employee reference table like that.....BRILLIANT!

Answer (score 1):

The following will give you the results you're looking for.

```
select 
    e.employee,
    create_count=(select count(*) from customers c where c.createdby=e.employee),
    mod_count=(select count(*) from customers c where c.lastmodifiedby=e.employee),
    create_own_count=(select count(*) from customers c where c.createdby=e.employee and c.acctman=e.employee),
    mod_own_count=(select count(*) from customers c where c.lastmodifiedby=e.employee and c.acctman=e.employee)
from (
    select employee=createdby from customers
    union
    select employee=lastmodifiedby from customers
    union
    select employee=acctman from customers
) e
```

**Note:** there are other approaches that are more efficient than this but potentially far more complex as well. Specifically, I would bet there is a master Employee table somewhere that would prevent you from having to do the inline view just to get the list of names.

Comment: Very nicely done! I wouldn't have thought of doing it that way....but it works great. The query is very efficient. THANK YOU!

Comment: I just have to use a better method of getting the employee list. I just tested it by using  Distinct(e.CreatedBy).... this will only work as long as each employee has created a record at some point.

Comment: If your employee names need to come from this same table, you'll need to  do separate selects using `UNION` to get the full (and distinct) list. I have updated the answer above to reflect this. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

this seems pretty straight forward.  Try this:

```
select a.employee,b.created,c.modified ....
from (select distinct created_by from data) as a
inner join
     (select created_by,count(*) as created from data group by created_by) as b
on a.employee = b.created_by)

inner join ....
```

Comment: I didn't get a chance to try this, but Yes I think it would work as well. I'll save it for a rainy day...or the next time i need a similar function. I had actually tried writing it this way, but got lost in the joins.

Comment: Thank you for posting, I Certainly appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

This **highly inefficient** query may be a rough start to what you are looking for. Once you validate the data then there are things you can do to tidy it up and make it more efficient.

Also, I don't think you need the `DISTINCT` on the `UNION` part because the `UNION` will return `DISTINCT` values unless `UNION ALL` is specified.

```
SELECT  
    Employees.EmployeeID,
    Created   =(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Cust_REc WHERE Cust_REc.CreatedBy=Employees.EmployeeID),
    Mopdified =(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Cust_REc WHERE Cust_REc.LastUser=Employees.EmployeeID AND Cust_REc.CreateBy<>Employees.EmployeeID),
    ModOwn    =
        CASE WHEN NOT Empoyees.IsManager THEN NULL ELSE
            (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Cust_REc WHERE AcctMan=Employees.EmployeeID)
        END,
    CreatedOwn=(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Cust_REc WHERE AcctMan=Employees.EmployeeID AND CReatedBy=Employees.EMployeeID)
FROM
    (       
        SELECT
            EmployeeID,
            IsManager=CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT AcctMan FROM CustRec WHERE AcctMan=EmployeeID)
        FROM
        (
            SELECT DISTINCT 
                EmployeeID
            FROM
            (
                SELECT EmployeeID=CreatedBy FROM Cust_Rec
                UNION
                SELECT EmployeeID=LastUser FROM Cust_Rec
                UNION
                SELECT EmployeeID=AcctMan FROM Cust_Rec
            )AS Z
        )AS Y
    )
    AS Employees
```

Comment: Hmm, couldn't get this to work. But the first suggestion is working.

Comment: Thank you for the trouble of looking at it. I do appreciate your effort.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with the Modified column. All the other columns worked okay. DCR example would work well with the join on an employees table if you have it.

```
SELECT  CreatedBy AS [Employee],
        COUNT(CreatedBy) AS [Created],
        --Couldn't get modified to pull the right results
        SUM(CASE WHEN LastUser = AcctMan THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) [Mod Own],
        SUM(CASE WHEN CreatedBy = AcctMan THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) [Created Own]
FROM Cust_Rec
GROUP BY CreatedBy
```

Comment: It is a tricky process. A good reason not to store all your data in one table :)